# What is the most efficient way to compare/sort items from two arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, implementation

I have a question about efficient implementation.  Lets say I have two arrays:

```
One array is all possible items in a house: Table, Chair, TV, Fireplace, Bed

The other is an array of items in a particular house: Table, TV, Bed
```

I also have two list boxes:

```
1. listbox for items in the house - the "HAS" list box
2. listbox items not in the house - the "NEEDS" list box
```

I need to list the items already in the house in the "HAS" list box as well as the items that are NOT in the house in the "NEEDS" list box.  It seems to me that nested "For each" loops would be a start to solving this problem but I am not exactly sure which case needs to be nested.  What is the most efficient way to accomplish a task like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allItems = (new [] {"Table", "Chair", "TV", "Fireplace", "Bed"});
var hasItems = (new [] {"Table", "Chair"});

var hasList = hasItems.ToList();
var needsList = allItems.Except(hasItems).ToList();
```

Comment: Just looked up Enumerable.Except implementation - it really uses internal Set class, so it must really provide the same performance. Actually I was not sure about this before.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allList = (new [] {"Table", "Chair", "TV", "Fireplace", "Bed"}).ToList();
var hasList = (new [] {"Table", "Chair"}).ToList();

var hasSet = new HashSet<string>(hasList);
var needsList = allList.Where(i => !hasList.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

That's ~ the fastest solution (at least, in [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation)).

Comment: First of all, HashSet is generic, so you need to specify HashSet<String>. Secondly, I think you mean not contains. The logic should look like this:

var needsList = allList.Where(i => !hasList.Contains(i)).ToList();