# How to compare two arrays and find best match?

Tags: arrays, compare, match

For example I have:

```
array[3] arr1 = {.5,.5,0}
array[3] arr2 = {.5,0,.5}
array[3] arr3 = {0,.5,.5}
array[3] findarr = {1,1,0}
```

Obviously, arr1 is the best match for findarr. I already have a simple algorithm working but I want to know if there is a formula for how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So "best match" means closest in numeric value with order considered? Anyway, let's see your algorithm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f = pow(arrX[0]-findarr[0],2) + pow(arrX[1]-findarr[1],2) + pow(arrX[2]-findarr[2],2);`

`pow(x,2) == x*x`

So, "the best match" will be array, with smallest `f`

Comment: hi thanks! thats what im using now but im not squaring. im going to add that

Comment: @user488792: Depending on what you are doing, you might also want to try `fabs(arrX[0]-findarr[0])` instead of `pow(...,2)`, or take the maximum of the absolute values of the differences.  These are different vector norms instead of Euclidean distance (the answer suggests using distance squared, which is equivalent for comparisons).

Answer (score 1):

Answered here already. Just go through it to get an idea.
You can do it in similar manner.

- [Algorithm - Check if 2 arrays have identical members ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245509/algorithm-to-tell-if-two-arrays-have-identical-members)
- [What is the best function compare two arrays ?](http://forum.processing.org/topic/what-is-the-best-function-compare-two-arrays)

A bit related.

- [What is the most efficient way to compare/sort items from two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140220/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-compare-sort-items-from-two-arrays)

In PHP, you can do it using [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.[**[+]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065431/compare-2-arrays-for-likeness)